# Unity Dependency Injection how to pass mapping name into sub objects resolved in parent objects constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have the following problem

I am developing a Windows service where I inject the repositories into the entities for data retrieval. However I have several repositories of a similar flavour which are to be resolved using the context the service is running under (runtime variable)

Below is a trimmed down example of what I am writing

```
public static void Main() {

IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IRepo, RepoBase>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

container.RegisterType<IRepo, RepoA>("processA", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

container.RegisterType<IRepo, RepoB>("processB", new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

container.RegisterType<IEntity, EntityA1>("ProcessA");
container.RegisterType<IEntity, EntityA2>("ProcessB");

var processType = "ProcessB"; //this is read from a queue and changes with every request the service processes

var entityInstance = container.Resolve<IEntity>(ProcessType);
entityInstance.DoSomething()             }


public RepoBase : IRepo {
 public virtual object ReturnData() {return baseData}             }


public RepoA : RepoBase {
public override object ReturnData() {
    var x = base.ReturnData(); 
    return x + RepoAData; }             }


public RepoB : RepoBase {
public override object ReturnData() { return RepoBData; }             }


public class EntityA1 : IEntity {
public EntityA1(IRepo repo){...}
public void DoSomething() {
    var data = repo.ReturnData(); 
    //....Do something with data }             }



public class EntityA2 : IEntity {
public EntityA2(IRepo repo){...}
public void DoSomething()   {
    var data = repo.ReturnData(); 
    //....Do something with data }             }
```

The problem I am having is that when I resolve IEntity I want to get the context processType passed to the resolving of IRepo so that it resolves to RepoA for ProcessA, RepoB for ProcessB etc.

Currently it resolves to RepoBase as the context is not being passed in.

Additionally I think I could do this by adding dependency attributes to the Entity constructor signature such as

```
public EntityA1([Dependency("ProcessA")] IRepo repo) {....}
```

However I do not want to litter my classes with this attribute as it tightly couples my service to my dependency injection registration/resolution etc which I want to keep separate and in one central location (the service layer and not in the business logic layer or further down).

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to do this at the point of registration.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this after many attempts at it

```
_container.RegisterType<IEntity, EntityA1>("processA",
                        new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IRepo>("processA")));
```

This then resolves the correct mapping of IRepo

```
var entityInstance = container.Resolve<IEntity>(processType);
```

This achieves what I wished which was to clarify this at the point of registration not resolving.

If anybody has improvements to the above I would be grateful to hear back from you

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a factory:

```
var entityInstance = myFactory.CreateEntity(ProcessType);
```

and

```
internal class EntityFactory
{
    public EntityFactory( IUnityContainer container )
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public IEntity CreateEntity( string processType )
    {
        return _container.Resolve<IEntity>( processType, new ParameterOverride( "repo", _container.Resolve<IRepo>( processType ) ) );
    }

    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
}
```

Comment: thanks @Haukinger let me put this into a micro implementation and get back to you.

Comment: ok not sure if I have implemented your suggestion correctly as you intended but when I do the above it still resolves IRepo to RepoBase.  Perhaps I should clarify it is the injected Repo instance which is not resolving as I wished since it is resolving the unnamed mapping not the named mapping for processType. Thanks

Comment: I edited the proposed solution, it gets a bit clunky this way, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this one the solution you provided worked however I wanted to achieve the same result at the point of registration rather than resolution.